# How to select columns from R dataframe?

Tags: r, extract

I know we can extract specific columns from R dataframe with `df[,c("A","B","E")]`. However, There are so many columns I want to pick out, and I can not type them one by one. I have a dataframe B that contains all column headers that I want to extract from Dataframe A. How can I extract columns from Dataframe A based on the headers I put in DataframeB ?

I tried `A[,B[, 1]]` but I got `incorrect number of dimensions` I got same error when I tried to print B[, 1].

With `dput(B)` I got `> dput(B)
c("A", "B", "C", 
"D", "E", "F", 
"G")`

Comment: Try `df[, names(B)]` that should do the job! Or `df[, B$values]` depending on where and how the names are stored in B.

Comment: I tried df[, names(B)]. i got result data frame with 0 columns and 2818356 rows. I want to try the second way, but since in B I don't have a header of it's column, how can i add header to it? Thanks

Comment: You could also do `df[, B[, 1]]` if the values are in the first column of B

Comment: It's weird. It tell me Error in B[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions. And When I do names(B) I got Null. When I print my B it's like [1] "A" [2] "B" [3] "C" I'm really confused how the data is stored

Comment: I can only get value with B[1] instead of B[,1]. However I only got the first value in B with B[1]. really appreciate your patience

Comment: Please include a minimum working  example, fe with `dput(droplevels(df))` and `dput(B)`

Comment: I updated my question. How should I use fe with dput(droplevels(df))? I got  'no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "character" '

Comment: Looks like B is a vector... df[, B]

Comment: Please also post `dput(df[1:10, 1:10])`